# test xargs before operating on it

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I am trying to do something like this on the command line in a while loop

```
....| xargs kill -9
```

The problem is that xargs is sometimes empty and kill command errors out. How do I test if xargs is NOT empty and operate on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing the `-r` flag to `xargs`:

```
... | xargs -r kill -9
```

Comment: That is a GNU extension to [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html)
(but an extremely useful one).